# Plausible reason why magic users aren't in charge

Tags: magic, warfare, politics

Setting: fantasy world in which non-magic users outnumber magic users, but are still very fearful of them, to the point of fighting a war to keep magic out of the country the story is set in. The whole story is based on the outcome of this war, as it begins directly afterward. 
Question: What is a plausible reason for why the magic users don't win against the human army? Is it enough to say that they were eventually overrun and repelled by the mundane soldiers, due to the disproportionate populations?

Comment: This is _very_ opinion-based as we have no clue how the magic in your world works and what limitations are imposed on it. Maybe all magic users are also born unknowingly wise and impossibly fair and utterly godlike and see no joy in commanding power because of a side effect of their magic. Maybe using magic hurts them. Maybe magic users just aren't trusted and are easily overpowered. Who knows?

Comment: Please note that the [tag:magic] tag provides guidance that, when included, the question should provide details concerning how magic functions in your world. Without that detail, we cannot provide answers that adequately address your problem.

Comment: I voted as unclear what you're asking because you didn't provide enough details about your magic so we can't provide thoughtful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible reasons
feel free to pick any you like

Magic is a poor weapon - arrows fly faster and more accurately than fireballs

Magic users have a code of ethics that keeps them from fighting well or at all - wizards all take an oath never to kill

Magic is good but there are too many muggle troops - each mage killed one hundred before they died, but there still remained thousands of foes.

Poor tactics - many times a more powerful army can be defeated if caught be surprise or in a bad condition, maybe there was an ambush were many mages were killed by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

### Motivation

Magic users may want to move to that country, but they ain't gonna fight a war over it. Why would they want to live somewhere where people are hostile to them?

On the other hand, the mundane people are protecting their way of life, and would go to war.

So no war is fought, or if one is fought, its only a faction of the magic users that fight. The mundane folk would fight *very* hard against them, being more motivated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, as long as the mundanes can produce more soldiers then the magic user can kill.  If each magic user can kill a hundred people before they die, then the mundane soldiers must have the population to produce a hundred fifty troops for every one magic user on the field.

Alternately  you could give you mundane advanced technology that can even the odd between them and the magic users, that way the mundane don't need a gigantic army and just one that twice as large as the magic user army.

Also remember war isn't all about numbers and fire power, bad strategies, poorly trained soldiers and incompetent generals can destroy  even the mightiest of empires